# move up and down elements in a multiple select not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, dropdownbox

I have created an angularjs app with multiple select upon which I am having up and down button , within which when I click up and down button corresponding movement of items should be done within the multiple select, I have a sample stuff which has been done with normal javascript which does the similar thing correctly like as shown in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn6fbwn9/)**, but when I tried to implement the same stuff in AngularJS its not working properly

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/681a520u/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <select id="select" size="9" ng-model="persons" ng-options="item as item.name for item in peoples | orderBy:'name'" multiple></select>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="moveUp()">Up</button>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="moveDown()">Down</button>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.peoples = [{
        name: 'Jacob'
    }, {
        name: 'Sunny'
    }, {
        name: 'Lenu'
    }, {
        name: 'Mathew'
    }, {
        name: 'Ferix'
    }, {
        name: 'Kitex'
    }];

    $scope.moveUp = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var i1=0, i2=1;
        while (i2 < select.options.length) {
            swapIf(select,i1++,i2++);
        }
    };

    $scope.moveDown = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var i1=select.options.length-1, i2=i1-1;
        while (i1 > 0) {
            swapIf(select,i1--,i2--);
        }
    };

    var swapVar = '';
    function swapIf(sel,i1,i2) {
        if ( ! select[i1].selected && select[i2].selected) {
            swapVar = select[i2].text;
            select[i2].text = select[i1].text;
            select[i1].text = swapVar;
            swapVar = select[i2].value;
            select[i2].value = select[i1].value;
            select[i1].value = swapVar;
            select[i1].selected = true;
            select[i2].selected = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: might be `orderBy:'name'` is causing an issue

Comment: @pankajparkar can we achieve this with a different approach without using `document.getElementById`, do you have any idea on this

Comment: This controller code is bad angular practice.  DOM manipulation should be done by directives, not controllers.

Comment: @tpie Yes you are right....I am thinking out how to simplify the code to angular specific

Comment: You can just manipulate the data in the controller.

Comment: @tpie its harder to manipulate if multiple are selected

Comment: will your data have duplicates in it?

Comment: @tpie may be sometimes, not sure

Comment: If there are no duplicates, it isn't that difficult.  If there are duplicates, giving each object a unique id key will assist greatly.

Comment: @but how we can do that

Comment: OK check my updated answer.  It works with the given data set (no duplicates)..let me think about dealing with duplicates for a minute...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`persons` will return an array of of whatever items are selected in the list.  One solution is to create a for loop that gets the `indexOf` of each item in the `persons` array. `splice` that items out of the `peoples` array, increment/decrement the index, and `splice` it back in to the `peoples` array.

Here is a new `moveUp()` function that can move up multiple selected items:

```
   $scope.moveUp = function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var idx = $scope.peoples.indexOf($scope.persons[i])
            console.log(idx);
            if (idx > 0) {
                var itemToMove = $scope.peoples.splice(idx, 1)
                console.log(itemToMove[0])
                $scope.peoples.splice(idx-1, 0, itemToMove[0]);

            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the updated `moveDown()` function:

```
   $scope.moveDown = function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var idx = $scope.peoples.indexOf($scope.persons[i])
            console.log(idx);
            if (idx < $scope.peoples.length) {
                var itemToMove = $scope.peoples.splice(idx, 1)
                console.log(itemToMove[0])
                $scope.peoples.splice(idx+2, 0, itemToMove[0]);

            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/681a520u/3/) (Not working so well, just kept for reference - see below)

This solution also maintains the separation between the View and the Controller.  The controller has the job of manipulating the data, the view displays that data.    This way we can avoid any uncomely entanglement.  DOM manipulations from within the controller are incredibly difficult to test.

**EDIT after some tinkering:**
So my previous solution worked in some cases but would perform oddly with different select combinations.  After some digging, I found it necessary to add track by:

`<select id="select" size="9" ng-model="persons" ng-options="item as item.name for item in peoples track by item.name" multiple>`

It seems the select would return the `persons` object with arbitrary selection orders and this was messing things up, especially after you clicked a few times, it seemed to get confused about where things were.

Additionally, I had to clone and reverse the persons array when moving items down because when adding `track by item.name` it returns the items in order, but if you try to iterate through the array, moving each one down, you are potentially impacting the location of other items in the array (further producing unpredictable behavior).  So we need to start from the bottom and work our way up when moving multiple items down.

Here is a solution in which I seem to have eliminated any unpredictable behavior when making multiple arbitrary selections:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/681a520u/6/)

**EDIT:**
One bug I have found is that weird things happen when you move multiple selected items all the way up or down, and then try to move it that direction one more time.  Any further movement without reselecting produces unpredictable results.

**EDIT:**
The unpredictable behavior mentioned in the previous edit was because the functions were seeing that, although the first item was in it's final position, the second, third, fourth, etc. items were not in an end position, and thus it tried to move them which led to crazy re-ordering of items that were already pushed all the one to the top or bottom.  In order to solve this I set a var that would track the position of the previously moved item.  If the current item was found to be in the adjacent position it would simply leave it there and move on.

The final functions look something like this:

```
$scope.moveUp = function () {
        var prevIdx = -1;
        var person = $scope.persons.concat();
        console.log($scope.persons);
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.persons.length; i++) {
            var idx = $scope.peoples.indexOf($scope.persons[i])
            console.log(idx);
            if (idx-1 === prevIdx) {
                prevIdx = idx
            } else if (idx > 0) {
                var itemToMove = $scope.peoples.splice(idx, 1)
                console.log(itemToMove[0])
                $scope.peoples.splice(idx-1, 0, itemToMove[0]);

            }
        }
    };
```

(Hopefully) [Final Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/681a520u/7/)

**EDIT:**
I enjoyed this problem and wanted to have a better solution in case there were duplicate list items.  This was fairly easy to solve by giving each object in the array a unique id key, and then changing `track by item.name` to `track by item.id`, and all works as before.

[Working Demo for Duplicates](http://jsfiddle.net/681a520u/8/)

Comment: your solutions works, but one issue is that say I am selecting `Lenu` and `Ferix` and then clicking the up button in such a way when they reached the top as `Lenu` as first position and `Ferix` as second position, again if we click the up button the order is changed to `Ferix` as first position and `Lenu` as second position, similarly at initial select all the option and click the up button you can see some unexpected ordering occuring

Comment: Yes, I noticed this as well.  This is because the way the function works, it gets the location of any selected items, and decrements the index.  I also found some odd behavior when selecting more than one or two items and moving down.  Working on it...

Comment: Any solution for that issue @tpie, I also tried from my side....but didn't get through

Comment: check the updated code..I eliminated a lot of the odd behavior...working on that last issue though.

Comment: Ok got it.  should be bug free now.

Comment: check the last edit if you need it to work with duplicate list items as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxmb2scv/2/)

You need to update your `swapIf` implementation so that it swaps the model, not options from the view:

```
function swapIf(sel,i1,i2) {
    if ( ! select[i1].selected && select[i2].selected) {

        var obj1 = $scope.peoples[i1];
        var obj2 = $scope.peoples[i2];
        $scope.peoples[i2] = obj1;
        $scope.peoples[i1] = obj2;
        select[i1].selected = true;
        select[i2].selected = false;
    }
}
```

Also, remove the `orderBy` in the view, and initialize the ordering in the controller using the `$filter` service.  The reason you need to do this is because the list is re-ordered whenever the user clicks the up/down button.

Comment: its working for single selection, but not seems working for multiple values selection

Comment: try it again - I've fixed that.

Comment: This is not the angular way.

Comment: It *IS* the angular way :P And it solves the OPs question using the same algorithm from the original post (which by the way is pretty cool).

Comment: @pixelbits your code works fine, but just like I am looking for something angular based

Comment: Sure, it can be more angular, I'll leave it that as an exercise for someone else

Comment: while it might solve the problem (and kudos to you for that) it uses controller-based DOM manipulation, which is not good practice with angular.