# How to move group of items up and down in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to show the items in ui in angular js and i need to move the
Items up and down in the ng-repeat table from external button.
i am able to move the items up and down but there is one more
condition in which i need to move group of items example:

```
id  reportname comments
1   report1     na
2   report2     test
2   report4     test
3   report3 test
3   report3     na
4   report4     test
```

I need to move the enitre group of `3,3` above `2,2` or move entire `2,2` below `3,3`.
Can someone please let me know how can we do that?

Comment: That's somehow unclear. Show us what have you tried

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713274/move-up-and-down-elements-in-a-multiple-select-not-working/29713760?noredirect=1#comment47564652_29713760

Comment: You can group these elements in a div and have another button to move it.

Comment: Where's your current move code? And why isn't this shown as javascript array instead of tab seperated values? Your app doesn't work from this data...we shouldn't have to either

Comment: @pixelbits, I believe that this is the same basic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working solution, using [Lodash](http://lodash.com) for a bunch of utility methods.

EDIT: Rewrote and refactored to cater for cases where not all items with same id are grouped together. This now only moves adjacent items with the same id, not all items with the same id in the array.

```js
angular.module('stackoverflow', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    id: 1,
    reportname: 'report1',
    comments: 'na'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    reportname: 'report2',
    comments: 'test'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    reportname: 'report4',
    comments: 'test'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    reportname: 'report3',
    comments: 'test'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    reportname: 'report3',
    comments: 'na'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    reportname: 'report4',
    comments: 'test'
  }];

  $scope.moveGroup = function(item, dir) {
    dir = normalizeDir(dir);
    firstIndexOfGroup
    var firstIndexOfGroup = findFirstIndexWithSameId(item);
    var endIndexOfGroup = findEndIndexOfGroup(firstIndexOfGroup, item);
    var itemsInGroup = $scope.data.slice(firstIndexOfGroup, endIndexOfGroup + 1);
    var idToSwapWith = ($scope.data[firstIndexOfGroup - 1] || {}).id;
    // if moving down, swap with first entry past group end
    if (dir === 'down') {
      idToSwapWith = ($scope.data[endIndexOfGroup + 1] || {}).id;
    }
    if (idToSwapWith > 0) {
      // remove from current position
      $scope.data.splice(firstIndexOfGroup, _.size(itemsInGroup));
      // insert group of items with same id at correct index
      var firstItemWithPrevIdIndex = _.findIndex($scope.data, 'id', idToSwapWith);
      if (dir === 'down') {
        firstItemWithPrevIdIndex = _.findLastIndex($scope.data, 'id', idToSwapWith) + 1;
      }
      var spliceArgs = [firstItemWithPrevIdIndex, 0].concat(itemsInGroup);
      $scope.data.splice.apply($scope.data, spliceArgs);
    }
  };

  $scope.moveItem = function(item, dir) {
    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);
    if (normalizeDir(dir) === 'up') {
      $scope.data.splice(index - 1, 2, item, $scope.data[index - 1]);
    } else {
      $scope.data.splice(index, 2, $scope.data[index + 1], item);
    }
  }

  function normalizeDir(dir) {
    switch ((dir || '').toString().toLowerCase()) {
      case 'up':
      case 'u':
        return 'up';
    }
    return 'down';
  }

  function findFirstIndexWithSameId(item) {
    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);
    for (var i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ($scope.data[i].id !== item.id) {
        break;
      } else {
        index = i;
      }
    }
    return index;
  }

  function findEndIndexOfGroup(startIndexOfGroup, item) {
    var index = startIndexOfGroup;
    for (var i = startIndexOfGroup + 1, len = _.size($scope.data); i < len; i++) {
      if ($scope.data[i].id === item.id) {
        index = i;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    return index;
  }
});
```

```css
.move-link-btn {
  font-size: smaller;
  color: lightblue;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
.move-link-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
td,
th {
  outline: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="stackoverflow" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Move Commands</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.reportname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.comments}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="move-link-btn" ng-click="moveItem(item, 'up')">Item Up</a>
          <a class="move-link-btn" ng-click="moveItem(item, 'down')">Item Down</a>
          <a class="move-link-btn" ng-click="moveGroup(item, 'up')">Group Up</a>
          <a class="move-link-btn" ng-click="moveGroup(item, 'down')">Group Down</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure why but it's easy to get groups to split apart from each other

Comment: @charlietfl I did a major rewrite of it, can you break the new version?

Comment: I beat on it...kicked it...threw fire at it ....   seems to hold up! :)

Comment: I'm glad I wrote it in Lavascript, then. It's immune to fire that way.

Answer (score 0):

I create small demo for up and down element in `ng-repeat` http://plnkr.co/edit/mBoIY5ZCCQA4sRSVHuQB?p=preview
Please see this and review it.

In above demo add

```
<input type="button" name="changeOrder" ng-click="changeReportOrder()" value="Change Order">
    <div ng-repeat="report in reports | orderBy:predicate:reverce">{{report.id}} {{report.reportname}} {{report.comments}}</div>
```

in body tag and

```
$scope.reports = [
    {id:1,reportname:'report1',comments:'na'},
    {id:2,reportname:'report2',comments:'test'},
    {id:2,reportname:'report4',comments:'test'},
    {id:3,reportname:'report3',comments:'test'},
    {id:3,reportname:'report3',comments:'na'},
    {id:4,reportname:'report4',comments:'test'}
    ];
    $scope.predicate = '-id';
    $scope.changeReportOrder = function(){
      if($scope.predicate == 'id')
        $scope.predicate = '-id';
      else
        $scope.predicate = 'id';
    }
```

In controller. and order change ascending/descending  of reports base on id when click on `Order Change` button.

Comment: Post your code in the answer...not just a link to a demo. Answers should be standalone...and demos are the extra to be able to test the code in the answer. Imagine 10 answers and no code visible..just a bunch of links. Would make the site very unfriendly for all users